# Getting testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value while running maven command

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

i want to run the mvn command from the command line by providing the testng.xml as parameterizing ( in future integrate with jenkins with paramaterization of xml files)

Running the command like this

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\MyProject-master04\MyStoreProject>mvn test -Dsurefire.xmlfiles=testng_smoke.xml -Durl=http://automationpractice.com/index.php

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.599 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-07T23:00:50-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) on project MyStoreProject: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test failed: testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value -> [Help 1]
```

Below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyStoreProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyStoreProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--    <properties>
            <xmlFiles>testng_all.xml</xmlFiles>
        </properties>-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${xmlFiles}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <appURL>${url}</appURL>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

And also in pom.xml how to resolve the highlighted tag

[image: part of po.xml]

i am struck for almost 2 days, tried all the solutions online but did not succeed.

Comment: You should change your command line from this: `-Dsurefire.xmlfiles=testng_smoke.xml` to `-DxmlFiles=testng_smoke.xml`  (check accurate the case is important...

Comment: Thank you for your response, tried with the same DxmlFiles=testng_smoke.xml and still getting the same testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value,